# Search and Replace using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

```
str = '{"name": "John", "company": "AB"C corp", "id": "12g: "123 12-12"}'
```

`B"C` replace with empty string ''

`g: "1` replace with empty string ''

Required string

```
str = '{"name": "John", "company": "A corp", "id": "1223 12-12"}'
```

What is the regex for this?

Tried

```
import re

str = re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9: "0-9]$', "", str)
```

Examples:

```
Valid: '"name": "John"'
Invalid: '"nam"e": "Jo"hn"'

Valid: '"id": "12A"'
Invalid: 'id: "12A"'
```

Comment: Regex? Why not `str.replace('B"C', '').replace('g: "1', '')`?

Comment: It can be any Letter / number and not B"C  or g: "1. Hence regex

Comment: Can you please state your requirements _accurately_? _What_ can be any letter/number? It's impossible to tell if you want `\w: "\w` or `\w: "\d` or `[a-z]: "\d` or one of the other 50 possible regexes.

Comment: Something like this would work for your cases `[A-Za-z][^"]*"\w` but as @Aran-Fey says, the requirements are not clear

Comment: Examples: Valid: '"name": "John"'
Invalid: '"nam"e": "Jo"hn"'

Valid: '"id": "12A"'
Invalid: 'id: "12A"'

Comment: Identifying an invalid string according to your examples is easy and clear. The problem is that the replacing rules are not clearly stated. Do you want to remove a pattern like `letter + quotation mark + letter`, or `letter + colon + quotation mark + number`, or `any character + quotation mark + any character`, or many other combinations there could be. Which one is it? Some of them may conflict with each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this!

check if you have a character, (a colon or space or both) that is followed by `"` and by a \w(character or number).

```
>>> s
'{"name": "John", "company": "AB"C corp", "id": "12g: "123 12-12"}'
>>> re.sub('\w[: ]*"\w','',s)
'{"name": "John", "company": "A corp", "id": "1223 12-12"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `\W"\W` and `\w: "\d` are the only cases you're worrying about?

Then try this:

```
str = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z](\: )?"[A-Z0-9])', "", str)
```

Comment: 1. no need for capturing group 2. no need to escape `:`

Comment: How to remove double quotes inside a double quotes. Ex "{"name": "John"}" needs to become "{'name': 'John'}"